# Validation of a css selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-selectors, css-selectors

Is there a way to programmatically check the validity of a javascript/jquery selector?

like `.class` is ok but `.class,` is not

programmatically in javascript or any backend language (besides going through jQuery source code)

so in pseudo code

```
 def selectorErrors(selector)

     // do nasty stuff to the selector
     if valid?
      return nil
    else
      return errors
    end
end
```

Comment: @Juhana No it is not

Comment: @Juhana It looks like it is: http://jsfiddle.net/w3gqd78e/

Comment: exactly my point. Is there a way to programmatically solve this arguement?

Comment: `try{ $('.class.'); } catch(e) { ... }`

Comment: You can add regex check

Comment: @RoyShmuli is there such a regex?

Comment: how about a try/catch on document.querySelector(str) - less overhead than jQuery, although there are some jQuery specific "selectors" that querySelector wont allow

Comment: the problem with try/catch is that I don't know what's wrong with it besides that it is wrong

Comment: you can catch exception string and compare to know exatly which exception occured.

Comment: To make question clearer, do you want to check for valid jQuery selectors or CSS ones?

Answer (score 7):

This should validate 99% of what you can throw at jQuery with far less overhead

```
function validateQuery(str) {
    try {
        document.querySelector(str);
        return true;
    }
    catch(e) {
        // something here to check WHY it's invalid
    }
    return false;
}
```

edit: ok, this wont tell you WHAT is wrong with it, but it does (quickly) check the validity - at least you'll only need to check WHY it's invalid, not IF :p

Comment: Instead of `document.querySelector(str);` shouldn't it just be: `jQuery(str);`? Because ya, jQuery has some pseudo selectors (':has(), ':eq()', etc...) not supported by `document.querySelector()` method

Comment: In fact, question isn't clear about it: `Validation of a javascript/css selector` & `javascript/jquery selector`

Comment: Here’s [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/meqruLzr/1/) based on your method to test selectors for validity.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71303374

Answer (score -2):

```
existOrValid('#a')

function existOrValid(a){

    if (/^[#,.]{0,1}[A-Za-z][0-9A-Za-z\-\._:]*$/.test(a)) {
    alert('valid');
}

}
```

Works on simple class ,id selectors but needs modification for nested queries

Answer (score -5):

`$('.a.b')`

If you want an intersection, just write the selectors together without spaces in between. So for an element that has an ID of a with classes b and c, you would write:

`$('#a.b.c')`

Comment: this doesn't check for validation, as in given a selector tell me if its good or not