# Check if CSS selector is valid

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

I have a field for users to input a CSS selector and I want to check if it's valid (according to [css3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar)). I tried to use expressions from [css3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#w3cselgrammar) as suggested in [another stackoverflow topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192045/regular-expression-for-valid-css-and-or-jquery-selector), but it didn't work - the regexp I built just didn't match valid selectors. What I have for now is simply:

```
try {
     document.querySelector(selector);
} catch (e) {
     // handle bad input
}
```

But it doesn't seem like a good solution - querySelector function is designed for getting elements, and checking of selector is just a side effect. Furthermore it doesn't provide any information about what is wrong with the selector.

What I'm looking for is something like `document.validateSelector` or library for parsing CSS selectors.

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it? This is the preferred approach as far as I know.

Comment: How are users inserting the selector? For example, for a class are the inputing `.className`? Basically, are you prefixing the `selector` with the appropriate identifier for `class` or `id`?

Comment: @Brett DeWoody, yes, they're supposed to type selectors just like in .css files, I don't change it in any way.

Comment: @torazaburo, well, it does work, but it just seams wrong) document.querySelector is not for that. In fact I'm just curious is there a more elegant solution.

Comment: It's fine. You're using `try` to pick up an error which is reported by a throw, which is how querySelector reports errors. The only reason to not use this and prefer some other solution is if you wanted details such as the type of error or its character position.

Comment: Are you testing if a selector is present on the page? Or if a selector name is a valid selector name, meaning it follows selector name rules?

Comment: Seems quite clear: "check if it's valid".

Comment: @BrettDeWoody, I'm testing if it follows selector name rules

Comment: This seems to work as expected - https://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/hvz9Le7s/. Inserting an invalid selector (starting with a number for example) results in an error.

Comment: @torazaburo: Based on the accepted answer the OP seems to be asking something else entirely - whatever that might be, it's certainly not the question we are looking at.

Comment: @BoltClock The question is simple: how to validate a string with css selector. This string is taken from an input field. OP asks for a better solution, in order to avoid try catch if the selector is not valid.

Comment: Related/duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31637782/validation-of-a-css-selector

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin I agree this question is unclear. The OP posts code which  successfully does something, then asks the question of how to do that. If his question was how to do this **without** `try/catch`, then the question should have stated that, hopefully including a note about why he thinks `try/catch` is so horribly bad. If he has the requirement to detect details or the character location of the error, which could possibly be the case based on the answer he accepted, then that also should have been stated clearly in the question.

Comment: @torazaburo OP describes that he found a potential solution, but using a `try` `catch`. It is not a correct approach, because it forces an error generation and use functionality that has a side effect of css validation, but is not actually a validator. He asks for correct ways to accomplish this. I see here everything clear and a good question, especially that author made a good research on the question.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin The point being discussed here is whether this question is unclear. In its original form, it **was** unclear; in fact, he asked **no question at all**. In any case, it remains unclear why you, or he, thinks the `try/catch` approach is problematic. `throw` is a perfectly standard JS mechanism for reporting errors, and `try/catch` is the perfectly standard JS mechanism for picking them up. Now, that he has edited his question, to ask for a library, then his question is off topic for a different reason, which is that it looking for a library.

Comment: @DmitriPavlutin I have no problem with you saying that you need a library to determine exactly **what** is wrong with a selector, but as I mentioned, that aspect was missing from the original question. In the absence of that requirement, there is no basis whatsoever for you asserting that the `try/catch` approach is "incorrect", other than personal preference or some kind of strange allergy to `throw`.

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, in the end it is a matter of personal preference. Thanks for your time on discussing this. I would drink with you a beer! Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a library to verify if the selector is valid, and probably get more details from parsing. Check the [css selector parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-selector-parser).

Comment: There's already a library, it's the CSS selector parser built into the browser. That "library" reports errors by throwing. I don't see any reason to bring in another parser.

Comment: Why generate runtime errors, if it is possible to avoid them. A library can give more details on an invalid selector. `document.querySelector(selector)` is designed to query the DOM, but not to check the selector validity.

Answer (score 36):

The problem with original idea is that it will search the entire document. *Slow*  !

However, searching an empty light-weight element that is not even attached to the DOM is **fast** ✌️!

```js
const queryCheck = (s) => document.createDocumentFragment().querySelector(s)

const isSelectorValid = (selector) => {
  try { queryCheck(selector) } catch { return false }
  return true
}

console.assert(isSelectorValid('p > > > a') === false)
console.assert(isSelectorValid('p > a') === true)
console.log('Test passed')
```

The following version is a bit more advanced with dummy fragment enclosure:

```js
const isSelectorValid = ((dummyElement) =>
  (selector) => {
    try { dummyElement.querySelector(selector) } catch { return false }
    return true
  })(document.createDocumentFragment())
  
console.assert(isSelectorValid('p > > > a') === false)
console.assert(isSelectorValid('p > a') === true)
console.log('Test passed')
```

Comment: this should be the best answer

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @kornieff hint, I've reached out to an answer for nodejs using jsdom, if it can help anyone :

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");
const { JSDOM } = jsdom;
const { document } = (new JSDOM('')).window;

const queryCheck = s => document.createDocumentFragment().querySelector(s)

const isSelectorValid = selector => {
  try { queryCheck(selector) } catch { return false }
  return true
}
console.log(isSelectorValid("a#x#y"), isSelectorValid("a?+"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since querySelector and CSS.supports('selector('+s+')') accept unclosed input like `a[href="foo`,
**let's use the built-in CSSStyleSheet API to check the selector can be used in a CSS rule:**

```js
let isv;
function isSelectorValid(sel) {
  if (!isv) {
    try {
      // Chrome 73 and newer
      isv = new CSSStyleSheet();
    } catch (e) {
      // This will fail on sites with an unusually strict CSP that forbids inline styles,
      // so you'll need to set `nonce` or reuse an existing `link` element.
      isv = document.head.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).sheet;
      isv.disabled = true;
    }
  }
  let res = false;
  try {
    // the leading space skips selector's trailing escape char
    const body = ` { --foo: "${Math.random()}"; }`;
    isv.insertRule(sel + body);
    res = isv.cssRules[0].cssText.endsWith(body);
    isv.deleteRule(0);
  } catch (e) {}
  return res;
}
```